# Why does my div.col expand to 110% when I set the background?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I set style="background-color: grey;" on my div.col containing `<h3> Contacts </h3>`, the color overflows by left and right. What can I do to solve it? It looks weird.

```html
<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/1.5.1/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
    <div id="app" class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h3 style="text-align: center; margin-top:2em; margin-bottom: 1em;">
                    Contacts
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: gray; width: 100%;">Favorite contacts</div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

This is how it looks like, and I want to "cut" the background by the vertical lines I drawn
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqPNb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because  Bootstrap's `.col` rules includes

```
   padding-right: 15px;
   padding-left: 15px;
```

Comment: Just tried adding ```padding: 0px; margin: 0px;``` to the div.col and it's still the same

Comment: Nope - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/LYYMgyV but note that the `.row` also has negative margin which might be your issue.

Comment: Just added it in a separate .css file and it works perfectly. Tyvm!